# SQL Date Col - Use DATE or Varchar?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, date, format

I have very simple code, but the issue is that when I convert a date column to Varchar(10), then I am not fetching distinct dates and sort is not working as desired; when I use DATE format, then I am fetching distinct dates and date sort is working, but I get datetime - 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM *(I don't want the time part)*
Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
--CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, (MyDate)), 0), 101) AS MonthValue,
 CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, (MyDate)), 0)) AS MonthValue
FROM dbo.Mytable
WHERE MyDate >= GETDATE()-366
ORDER BY MonthValue DESC
```

Comment: *Never* store date values are a `varchar`.  Use the appropriate type.  Also, what do you mean by `when I use DATE format ... I get DATETIME`.  Is it a `DATE` or is it a `DATETIME`?

Comment: CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, (MyDate)), 0)) AS MonthValue. When I use CONVERT(DATE.. ) returned values are like 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM. I do not want to display 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I still don't understand.  If you're converting it to a `DATE`, it won't have the `TIME` component.  Where are you seeing a `DATETIME`?

Comment: Actually, I don't see it in SSMS, but in a dropdown in the ASPX page

Comment: That's an issue with your ASPX page, not SQL.

Comment: If same sql returns CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, (MyDate)), 0), 101) AS MonthValue then I see just dates (the commented line) but not in second case. So where do I make a change?

Comment: If you do it that way, you're converting it to a string.  As a string, the browser has no concept of it being a date, and will display its literal value.  If it's actually a date, it will use the browser's default display, which looks to be with a time.  Since no time was supplied, it uses the default of midnight.  To fix this, you either need to adjust it on the ASPX side by formatting the date, or on the SQL side by converting it to your preferred format (a good source is here: [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1471/dates#t=201702161548109921354)).

Comment: In my personal opinion, I would recommend fixing it in your ASPX code.

Comment: You're probably using a date picker control or something that's always displaying a time component. Since there isn't one in your DATE field, it's assuming zero = 12 AM. Check for a setting on your control for formatting the displayed date, or maybe find a better custom control.